# Which has more power Kruskal Wallis or Cox regression?

Tags: survival, kruskal-wallis-test

I am analysing behavioural data that is the latency for predators to consume prey within a ten minute trial. The data are not normally distributed, and I originally analysed them using Kruskal Wallis. However, it was suggested to me as I have individuals that never consumed prey, that I would be better off using Cox regression as this would account for censored data. There is no great difference between the results of each analysis so I wanted to know how best to choose which one to use? Is there a difference in the power or sensitivity of these two analyses?

Answer (score 1):

Choice of statistical test should be based on the properties of your data not 'power'. Based on your description the Cox's regression is indeed more appropriate as it explicitly handles censored data and is designed for time to event type data. Kruskal Wallis will be biased if censoring occurs, with the extent dependent on the proportion of events that are censored. If you have a censored event how are you coding it for KW?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. For the KW, individuals that did not consume prey were given the value of the total length of the trial plus one (600001 milliseconds).

Comment: That would explain why the results are similar, given that KW is non-parametric, so the exact magnitude of your truncation is not critical, just where it ranks (beginning or end, with the end being the one you want in this case). Cox's is still the more usual approach given the nature of the data.